# Dataframe with conflicting float formatting

Tags: python, pandas, scientific-notation

I have the below dataframe:

```
pd.DataFrame({'Full Dataset': m1_baseline.params,
          'Train Set': m1_train.params})
```

Which produces the below table:

```
                     Full Dataset   Train Set
Intercept            6.078966e+01    62.479667
DISTANCE             4.418002e-03    0.001389
AP_TOTAL_ARRIVALS   -8.944526e-07   -0.000006
AL_TOTAL_FLIGHTS    -7.643211e-06   -0.000008
Lunch               -4.391630e+00   -5.179138
```

Obviously the use of scientific notation in the first column but not the second is confusing.

Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Do you want to remove the scientific notation?

Comment: I want both columns to be in the same format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try [df.style:](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/style.html)

```
df.style.format('{:.2f}')
```

This fill have numbers upto 2 decimal places and you can change the number to change it how many ever decimal places you want